# Trying to map over array of objects in React, returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map over an array of objects. I don't understand why `comment.commenter_comment` is "undefined". I thought map and dot notation worked on objects if they were nested within an array, am I misunderstanding this?

I ultimately want to display "k" (`commenter_comment: 'k'`) for the first loop, and so on...

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Comments(props) {
  var holder = []
  if (props.post && props.post.comments_text) {
   holder.push(Object.values(props.post.comments_text))

    return (
      <div>
        {holder.map((comment) => {
          return (
            <div>
               {comment.commenter_comment} 
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

For reference, `props` looks like this:

```
props = {
    post: {
    comment: true,
    comments_text: 
        {
        -Mk0Bzc8T-p6ATuwn_2T: {commenter_comment: 'k', commenter_handle: 'SHARK1', commenter_uid: 
        '1lJQ2rVtzRdgp4K1SZJbXAopsfm1'}
        -Mk0CdvBkgIwfsZATPsS: {commenter_comment: 's', commenter_handle: 'SHARK1', commenter_uid: 
        '1lJQ2rVtzRdgp4K1SZJbXAopsfm1'}
        -Mk0Cht7il7Ohn6OiziB: {commenter_comment: 's', commenter_handle: 'SHARK1', commenter_uid: 
        '1lJQ2rVtzRdgp4K1SZJbXAopsfm1'}
        -Mk-AnrSJVU7sOmeVP_n: {commenter_comment: 'testing14', commenter_handle: 'SHARK1', 
         commenter_uid: '1lJQ2rVtzRdgp4K1SZJbXAopsfm1'}
    }
    handle: "bug1",
    key: "-MjLYDJlHXnO-HaL6R58",
    title: "k"
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help or tips.

Comment: I think you want `holder.push(...Object.values(props.post.comments_text))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making your `holder` to be an array containing a single value, and that value will be the array of values from the object:

```
  var holder = []
  if (props.post && props.post.comments_text) {
   holder.push(Object.values(props.post.comments_text))
```

You want to map over all the object values, not the `holder`. While you could access `holder[0]`, I think your code would be less confusing if you removed it entirely.

```
export default function Comments(props) {
    const comments = props.post?.comments_text;
    return !comments
        ? null
        : Object.values(comments).map(comment => (
            <div>
                {comment.commenter_comment}
            </div>
        ));
};
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function Comments(props) {
  const [holder, setHolder] = useState(Object.values(props.post.comments_text));

    return (
    holder.length != 0 ?
      <div>
        {holder.map((comment) => {
          return (
            <div>
               {comment.commenter_comment} 
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div> : null
    )
}
```

Here we are making a holder state and setting it the value of "post.comments_text". It is best practice to use the react hooks when handling state in the functional components.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).